# Why is there a horizontal scrollbar when my total width is 100vw?

Tags: html, css

Here is the code. I don't know why there is a horizontal scrollbar.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="width: 100vw">
<div style="float: left; width: 220px">a</div>
<div style="float: left; width: calc(100vw - 220px)">b</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a valid question even though it's simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the default `margin` in the browser stylesheet.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body style="width: 100vw">
  <div style="float: left; width: 220px">a</div>
  <div style="float: left; width: calc(100vw - 220px)">b</div>
</body>

</html>
```